# Heroku dev Postgres database row limit/maximum row

Tags: postgresql, heroku, row

Heroku has just launched several new database plan, one of those plans is dev plan. [In heroku's Postgres blog](https://postgres.heroku.com/blog/past/2012/4/26/heroku_postgres_development_plan/), dev plan described as a plan that's planned to replace the current 5MB free database plan.

What's interesting in that blog post is that dev plan using row limit rather than size limit. I've run several experiments using different methods but it seems like there's just no limit. ***Just curious, does anyone know the hard limit?***

---

***First Experiment:***

The first experiments is using manual `INSERT INTO` from Navicat on my mac and executed it several hundred thousand times by copy pasting it:

```
INSERT INTO table_name VALUES ('x');
```

The result, it runs about 2 days to get almost 200.000 rows. Well, it's not reaching the hard limit yet.

***Second Experiment:***

The second experiments is using `psql` and the number of record inserted is bumped to 1 million:

```
INSERT INTO table_name SELECT * FROM generate_series(1, 1000000);
```

Everything's running fine, the records are inserted, more than a million rows in the dev plan, and no row limiting seems running in Heroku's postgres.

Another test was thrown, and it was bumped to 10 million records:

```
INSERT INTO table_name SELECT * FROM generate_series(1, 10000000);
```

---

Seeing my data size reached 4GB had made me stopped the test. I guess it's safe to presume that the dev plan is good for testing massive data amount, and not to forget that it's still in public beta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Heroku announced](http://blog.heroku.com/archives/2012/7/16/heroku_postgres_basic_plan_and_row_limits) that 10,000 row limit on dev.

Comment: yes, I just got it yesterday, why did I get a late email notification on the announcement.. :(

anyway, it's also documented in the devcenter: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-dev-plan#limits

Answer (score 1):

There is no limit set yet as far as I know, but I did see a quote on HackerNews stating that it would be somewhere in the region of 10^3.

http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=3916369